# Colab - How can I download CSV to my files on my computer

Tags: google-colaboratory

1. from google.colab import files
2. files.download('a.csv')

Can I change step2 to another path on my computer, not the default path?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: You could change your browser defaults to save to the location you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file manager panel.

Use View > Table of contents to show the sidebar then click the Files tab. Right-click the file and select Download.